# What happened to the silent who was injured by Canton?

Tags: doctor-who, the-silence

At the beginning of season 6, Canton shoots a silent and takes it to an "inescapable" prison where he recorded it saying "You should kill us all on sight" and then leaves it alone.

Is it ever explained or are there any theories on what happened to that silent? 
Does the government still have that silent which can be questioned or dissected, etc?

Comment: Unfortunately no-one remembers what happened to it...

Comment: What happened to what?

Answer (score 8):

It is never explained or revisited ever again. That particular Silent is not one of the ones we see in the montage later on. The best we can do is guess that:

- No one remembers that it was there. As we see from Canton's behavior in the TARDIS, the fact that the Silence even exist eventually fades from memory, so after some amount of time Canton will forget what's in the box. They will remember it was built for The Doctor but that's probably it.
- Someone probably killed it. Eventually, someone is going to decide to dismantle the "prison" they built for The Doctor and find the Silent in there. As this is a military installation, there will probably be at least one armed guard in the area. As per orders, the minute anyone sees the Silent they will try to kill it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that Silent would have succumbed to it's injuries in that vault, as the physician called on site clearly didn't remember it, leave alone healing it.